# Is it possible to update an app from another publishing account but with the right key

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Let's say that  a publisher `publisherA` published an app `AppA` on his account with the `KeyA` key.

Is it possible for `publisherB` to do an update of the `AppA` application(with the same package name) if he has the `KeyA` key.

`publisherA` and `publisherB` are not linked to the same publishing account.

All docs from Google I read talk about the importance of the key but never talk about the publishing account.

Any authenticated answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this. `publisherB` would not see the app on their developer console, so it wouldn't be possible to update it.

If they tried to get around it by uploading an APK with the same package name, it would get rejected as non-unique.

If you're working as a team, or someone has taken over a project, you'll probably want to use the multiple user account options. You can link other users to the account and set what permissions they have. If the original publisher is unreachable, you'll have to change the package name and somehow convince current users to switch over.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Google can do this manually, just send them a support-request and they can transfer applications from one account to another. It is still not possible for two accounts to have the same application in their management account, but you can transfer the app.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I assume that the original publisher would have to be the one sending the support request? Still, better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks!In fact publisherB is not from our team but is a customer.
And if i unpublish some of my apps, could publisherB republish them(same package name, same key) and the user will see it as an update?

Comment: I don't think so, or at least I haven't seen anything saying that would work. I would try submitting a support request to Google, as theomega suggested. It seems the most straightforward way to go about it.

Comment: The app is already in the good account(the customer's one), but have been signed with the bad key.
I send a request to Google 3 days ago for my "same key, other account" question, but I don't have any answer yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the key from publisherA to update an app from publisherB's account. A key belongs to a particular account.